# associate a row of a list box with a row of a DB table

Tags: delphi, listbox

How can i associate a row of a list box with a row of a DB table?

I created a firemonky mobile application. On the form i drop a listbox. The listbox is filled with an item from a database.

```
    zQuery1.Close;
    ZQuery1.Open;
    ListBox1.Items.Clear;
      While not ZQuery1.Eof do
      Begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(ZQuery1.Fields[1].AsString);
      ZQuery1.Next;
    end;
    ZQuery1.Close;
```

Displayed is the name of a person.

Now when i doubleclick on the name of the person i want the open a second form with detailed information from that person (available in record). Can someone help me if this can be done?

I want to create an app on iPad so when someone taps on the detail button in the listbox there is more information of that person.

Comment: You will need to store a reference to the unique ID in the database along with each item. This can be done by using `AddObject` passing a pointer to this ID.

Comment: @Jerry, what about LiveBindings ? I'd say it's possible to do this task in few clicks, though I don't know how.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Do you want to know how to handle a double click? How to open a new form? How to read info out of your DB?

Comment: @David i want to show more detailed info from that person but i don't know how to get that information when someone taps on the detailed button on the listbox (addobject?). I would appreciate it when someone can give me an example.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to associate a row of the list box with a row of the DB table? You should edit the question to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: @David Yes that is exactly what i mean (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: OK. Now click the edit button above and improve the question. Details must be in question and not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using listbox.items.add, you need to use listbox.items.addobject. For the purposes of the code below, I am assuming that the primary key of the table will be returned in zquery1.fields[0].

```
zQuery1.Close;
ZQuery1.Open;
ListBox1.Items.Clear;
While not ZQuery1.Eof do
 Begin
  ListBox1.Items.AddObject (ZQuery1.Fields[1].AsString, 
                  tobject (zquery1.fields[0].asinteger)
  ZQuery1.Next;
 end;
ZQuery1.Close;
```

In order to access the stored id, you would write something like this

```
avariable:= longint (listbox1.Items.Objects[listbox1.itemindex]);
```